# Open GL ES : how to repeat a texture over a plane?

Tags: java, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, arcore

I would like to create a 0.2 m x 1.05 m plane using openGL ES 2.0 (for Android => Java) and cover it with a repetitive square texture (size 0.1 m x 0.1 m). Thus, I would have 10.5 textures over the length and 2 over the width.

Anybody could help with some code to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [`glTexParameteri`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml) and set `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` and `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T` to `GL_REPEAT`.

Answer (score 2):

Like G.M. said it's easy, just set the texture to sample repeatedly so that when UV values are under or over (0 - 1) it just wraps. I don't use Java but it'll roughly look like this:

```
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, imgWidth, imgHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, loadedImg);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

// LOOKING DOWN Y AXIS
//  TRIANGLE1       TRIANGLE 2
//  *0              *3   *5
//
//  *1   *2              *4

//                          POS                 UVs
    float vertices[] = { 0.f, 0.f, 0.f,         0.f, 0.f,
                         0.f, 0.f, 0.2f,        0.f, 2.f,
                         1.05f, 0, 0.2f,        10.5f, 2.f,

                         0.f, 0.f, 0.f,         0.f, 0.f,
                         1.05f, 0.f, 0.2f,      10.5f, 2.f,
                         1.05f, 0.f, 0.f,       10.5f, 0.f };
```

Basically instead of the far sides of the plane being (1, 1) the far sides have UV values of (10.5, 2), wrapping over ten times.